# Quarto: Pagebreak before all level 1 headings

Tags: yaml, markdown, quarto

I am new to [Quarto](https://quarto.org/) and I don't know yet how to apply global styles for PDF documents. Obviously I can't use CSS to render PDFs. So what is the equivalent for PDF?

How can I, for example, add a pagebreak automatically before each level 1 heading?

Thank you!
winnewoerp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this [section](https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/pdf-basics.html#latex-includes) in the quarto documentation. You could for instance use the `include-in-header` functionality and this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131015/page-break-after-every-section), e.g.

```
---
format:
  pdf: 
    include-in-header: 
      text: |
        \let\oldsection\section
        \renewcommand\section{\clearpage\oldsection}
---


# First Section

## First Subsection

# Second section
```

Comment: Thank you! Works as expected. Though I must admit that I still don't know exactly what I'm doing here. :)